# Unable to load any code to PROD due to Code Coverage of 63% but none of my personal code is below 82 % Test coverage!

Tags: code-coverage, failing-tests

I deployed some small triggers to my PROD environment to make life a bit better. However currently noticed that my tests aren't current anymore and I want to update them (as it's stopping me from deploying any code)

I read on this website that only your own code (and not packaged stuff) should be taken into account for the code coverage calculations (and the right to deploy). However when I look at my code coverage (see items in my picture in yellow) none of my triggers are below 81% code coverage!

As I'm unable to touch the other code/test items I really don't know what to do anymore. I've already removed some of my own triggers on PROD through IDE thinking I could deploy them back once the Code Coverage was ok and I could adjust my Test scripts but this didn't do anything,

Any help is dearly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I remember running into the issue with communities and found this post which is a couple years old now but I'm assuming still valid: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000093E5IAI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known Salesforce issue. When you enable Chatter Answers, a couple of classes are created in system without its test classes. 
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHfAAM

The details say that its scheduled to release for Spring'15. There are workarounds given there, so you can directly use them.

Also you might want to check this link too from the developer forum :
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000A4tAIAS

Combination of both these links is the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've enabled additional SF features like Communities and Chatter Answers. You'll notice that the coverage on the ChatterAnswersRegistrationController is 0%. You need to write a test class to provide coverage for that class along with adding additional code to other classes like the CommunitiesLandingController that you only have 33% coverage on. When you enable features like that, its your responsibility to provide test class coverage for their controllers.

Answer (score -1):

Try reseting the current code coverage on PROD by going to the Apex Classes page in Setup and running all tests. It may be the case that certain changes made on production have lowered your code coverage since the previous deployment. Also, make sure that there's no extra classes/triggers in PROD that aren't in your sandbox.